# How to hide all images using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm injecting JavaScript code into a website for personal use, using a Google Chrome extension... I'd like to hide all images before the page loads... I've got the script to run before anything loads, but can't seem to get the correct code to hide the array of images... something like:

```
function beforeload(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.display = "none"
}
```

Basically i want all the image tags to have style="display:none" added to the attributes. how do i do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to loop on them

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i = 0; i < images.length;i++ ) {
    images[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you run `getElementsByTagName` on each iteration? I'm guessing you meant to do `images[i]...` in the loop body...

Comment: @Sean Kinsey: thanks for catching this, I forgot to change it before pasting the code here.

Answer (score 5):

Amr has got the way to do it with javascript. If you add jquery to the page, it only takes one line

```
$('img').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will only hide images of all image elements

```
let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    let images_length = images.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < images_length; i++) {
      images[i].style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
    }
```

but what if images are displayed using CSS ?
Solution for all elements

```js
 let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    let images_length = images.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < images_length; i++) {
      images[i].style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
    }

    /** now also hide images which are implemented in css */
    let all_elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    for(let i = 0 ; i < all_elements.length ; i++){
      all_elements[i].style.setProperty("background-image","unset","important");
    }
```

```css
.image {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  background-image : url(https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/aerial-view-main-faisal-mosque-600w-1242735640.jpg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/aerial-view-main-faisal-mosque-600w-1242735640.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<div class="image"></div>
<div> To show images plz comment/remove js </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this out:
http://ncthakur.itgo.com/js09.htm

It's not exactly what are you looking for, but you can use some part of it.

It took me 7 seconds to find it on google ;)